# GetTrackedAchievements returning number rather than list

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I was using [a function in the world of warcraft lua API](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/api/GetTrackedAchievements) to make an addon.

My goal was simply to get a list of all tracked achievements the player currently had. The documentation seemed to suggest it should return a list, yet I am getting a number. My code is as follows:

I tracked 6 achievements, 4 of which were in the zone I was testing in.

```
Addon = LibStub("AceAddon-3.0"):NewAddon("LocationAchievements", "AceConsole-3.0", "AceEvent-3.0")
function Addon:OnInitialize()
  Addon:Print(ChatFrame1, "Successfully initialized")
end
function Addon:DisplayAchievements()
  Addon:Print(ChatFrame1, UnitName("Player").." has changed to zone "..GetZoneText())
  local achievements = GetTrackedAchievements()
  Addon:Print(ChatFrame1, "Type of achievements variable: "..type(achievements))
  Addon:Print(ChatFrame1, "Number of tracked achievements: "..GetNumTrackedAchievements())
end
Addon:RegisterEvent("ZONE_CHANGED_NEW_AREA", "DisplayAchievements")
```

When I enter a new area, I receive the following output to my chat box

> Crowmonk has changed to zone Shadowmoon Valley
>
> Type of achievement variable: number
>
> Number of tracked achievements: 6

How can this be fixed? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It appears to return multiple values.  http://www.wowwiki.com/API_GetTrackedAchievements http://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GetTrackedAchievements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua supports [multiple return values](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html). These come as a list, rather than an array or table/object *(arrays and tables are actually the same thing in Lua)*

If you want a certain index:

```
value = select( index, GetTrackedAchievements() )
```

To iterate over these values of unknown length:

```
for val in pairs( GetTrackedAchievements() ) do
    print(val)
end
```

[pairs/ipairs](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html) can be called with lists as well as tables.

They can be fed back to another function as X parameters, in fact, `print( GetTrackedAchievements() )` will output all values, or converted to a table by creating a pseudo-literal: `{ GetTrackedAchievements() }` as you already found out, analogous to `{ 1, 2, 3, ["foo"] = "bar" }`

The reverse of that, forming a list out of the values in a table, is unpack:

```
x,y,z = unpack(tbl)
```

If the table `tbl` has more than three values, additional ones are discarded.

Answer (score 1):

found the error:

```
local achievements = {GetTrackedAchievements()}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: Wrapping a function call with braces like that constructs a table from the return values.